# Attempting to pass pointers to API function from Tcl

Tags: c, pointers, tcl

I'm trying to write a Tcl script to interface with an FTDI USB device (Windows platform).  I've gotten functions from the FTDI API with a single input parameter to work, but an API function called 'FT_GetDeviceInfoDetail' is causing me grief.

The API function call is as follows:

```
FT_STATUS FT_GetDeviceInfoDetail (DWORD dwIndex, LPDWORD lpdwFlags, LPDWORD lpdwType, LPDWORD lpdwID, LPDWORD lpdwLocId, PCHAR pcSerialNumber, PCHAR pcDescription, FT_HANDLE *ftHandle)
```

where LPDWORD,PCHAR, and FT_HANDLE are all pointers to memory spaces of varying sizes.

Using ffidl, I specify the function call like this:

```
ffidl::callout _GetDeviceInfoDetail {uint32 pointer-var pointer-var \
            pointer-var pointer-var pointer-var pointer-var \
            pointer-var} uint32 \
        [ffidl::symbol $dll FT_GetDeviceInfoDetail]
```

Here's where it gets interesting.  In Tcl, for all the pointer parameters getting passed to the API, I'm setting variables like this:
             set *variablename* [binary format s 0]

When I call the function, I pass in the variable names (i.e., 'foo', NOT '$foo') for all the pointers and (somewhat miraculously) the function returns an 'OK' status.  At this point, theoretically, the contents of the variables I passed in will contain some data in a binary string format.

I then attempt to 're-construct' the string representation of the binary data by doing:

```
[binary scan $foo s outstring]
```

at which point Windows intervenes and tells me that "Tclsh has stopped working".

I suspect the function is overwriting the memory space for one or more of the variables, but I'm not sure what to do about it.  So far, perhaps the best idea that's occurred to me is to write a C extension to Tcl that will call the API, fill in the data structure, then pass the structure back to Tcl somehow.

Can anyone point me to a method to do this in pure Tcl? (Sorry about the pun; I couldn't resist!)

Comment: Callbacks are tricky with ffidl IIRC. You might be better using a different approach, such as building a little extension package so that your glue can be written in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After playing around with various binary format options, I found that if I do "set foo [binary format xn]" (where "foo" is the pointer I wish to create and "n" is the number of bytes for which to allocate space), and then pass the name foo as the pointer in the function call, that the function appears to work correcly (at least the Tcl interpreter doesn't crash!).

Answer (score 0):

My ffidl is a bit rusty so bear with me. My suspicion is that because you are handing over variable names that are set as:

```
set varname [binary format s 0]
```

that the lpSerialNumber and lpDescription fields are causing the overwriting. Both those fields can be as large as 16 bytes. For those fields, a variable  initialized to a 16 byte string of nulls might work, i.e.

```
set serno [string repeat "\0" 16]
```

should give you the space you need for the lpSerialNumber field, for example. Anyway, that what I would try in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I gave it a try, and then the function call gave me the message "parameter 1 must be a binary string"...